# Shaving(hair cuts) on Rosh Chodesh

Tags: halacha, hair, rosh-chodesh-new-month, danger, rabbi-yehudah-hechasid

What is the reason that hair cuts are not allowed(or advisable) on Rosh Chodesh according to Rav Yehuda Hachassid? A lot of things mentioned in the tzavvah should be avoided because of danger is this also because of danger or is it more of a reason of a yom tov?

Comment: I don't know why people are making so much noise about a Tzavaah written for his sons. Nevermind the fact that most of the stuff are most likely his own Minhagim and have nothing to do with Dina DeGemara.

Comment: you mean the Magen Avraham and the Mishna Brurah are making noise?

Comment: Yes. All the Aharonim spent a lot of time on this. I still wonder why.

Comment: I don't think anyone has any idea what he was thinking when he wrote a lot of things.